# How does one fix a spelling mistake in Netbeans when it detects a spelling error?

Tags: netbeans

So Netbeans 8.1 has a spellchecker than finds misspellings in comments. While it is able to underline misspelled words in red, I can't for the life of me find an option to correct the spelling. Surely if it is able to detect a misspelled word, it also has an option to fix the mistake right? Where the hell is this option!? All my searches have resulted in people asking to turn the feature off altogether, or outdated articles asking for the feature period.

Comment: Use `Alt + Enter` to fix error.

Comment: Is there a menu option for that, or is it only a keycombo? This does work btw, so thanks! I don't understand why it isn't in the right click context menu like every other application on earth.

Comment: Nope, (or I'm wrong) its common in all major IDEs like Netbeans, Jetbrains, Eclipse to use `Alt + Enter` to fix syntactical errors or misspelled words.  In word processors or web browsers we use Right Click right? :)

Answer (score 1):

As per Shashanth's comment use `Alt + Enter` to get suggestions of possible corrections.